# Idiomatic way of creating duration or future date

Tags: go

What would be the idiomatic way of getting a duration between two dates or basically getting a future date based on the current. Right now I'm using the below code to achieve that.

```
yearSpan := time.Date(time.Now().Year()-1, time.Now().Month(), 
time.Now().Day(), time.Now().Hour(), time.Now().Minute(), time.Now().Second(), 
time.Now().Nanosecond(), time.UTC)

yearDuration := time.Now().Sub(yearSpan)

header.Add("Expires", time.Now().Add(futureDate).String())
```

I've pretty much looked everywhere in books and sites but I couldn't find any idiomatic way creating a duration. Any thoughts on how to refactor the above code in a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[time.Duration](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) is defined as `type Duration int64`, so basicly you just do basic math to get the duration you want.

For example ([Play with it](http://play.golang.org/p/nm8WZXJY49)) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

const avgYear = time.Hour * 24 * 365

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fmt.Println("Now", time.Now().String())
    fmt.Println("Last Year", time.Now().Add(-avgYear).String())
    fmt.Println("Next Year", time.Now().Add(avgYear).String())
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the so much neater answer :)

Comment: for some reason I completely forgot that I once used `time.Sleep(time.Minute * 1)` *sigh*